# Clickable (Taparea) on a HTML banner in firefox opens up Outlook along with a new tab

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, google-web-designer

I have created a HTML banner using GWD (Google Web Designer) that has a click (taparea) which should open up Outlook or any email client.

It is working fine on IE and Chrome, but when I open the HTML banner on Firefox and click the taparea (clickable area) it also opens up a 'new tab' along with outlook which I do not want.

Tried checking js code to see if there is any event triggering it or '`window.close()`' function but could'nt find any.

Can anybody help me in getting this fixed
or
suggest any fix to close the blank tab (tried `window.close` but as expected it would close up the HTML banner tab itself)

Your assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Azan

Comment: Could you add the code of the taparea you are talking about ?

Comment: Hi @LorenzMeyer,

Here's the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gwd-firefox-i2hzs

have created a copy of it on codesandbox, see if this helps.

Comment: This code in index.js is meant to open a new tab. If it shouldn't you should point to the part in the more than 3000 lines that is supposed to open Outlook instead. You cannot expect someone to read 300+ lines to point you to your problem.